# Chess match where first to win game wins match. Probability of winning is p and q, of draw is 1-p-q. Find mean, PMF, and variance of match duration.

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance, means, chessboard

**Question**
Fischer and Spassky play a sudden-death chess match whereby the first player to win a game wins the match. Each game is won by Fischer with probability $p$, by Spassky with probability $q$, and is a draw with probability $1 — p — q$.

- What is the probability that Fischer wins the match?

> Fischer wins = draw the first $(n — 1)^{th}$ games and win the last game. 
>  $$P\text{(Fischer wins)} = \sum_{i=1}^n(1-p-q)^{n-1}\cdot p = \frac{p}{p+q}$$

- What is the $PMF$, the mean, and the variance of the duration of the match?

> [image]

**Doubt :** I know that $Var[X] = E[X^2] -E[X]^2$, however, can't follow the arithmetic calculation provided in solution. Help me understand how $E[X]$ end up as $(P+1)^{-1}$ ?  I supposed $E[X]^2$ is $(p+q)^{-2}$ in this case.

Can someone please explain in more steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions are wrong.  P(Fisher wins)=$p\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-p-q)^n=p\frac{1}{1-(1-p-q)}=\frac{p}{p+q}$

Let $X$ be the duration of the match .  $E(X)=(p+q)\sum _{k=1}^\infty k(1-p-q)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{p+q}$,  $E(X^2)=(p+q)\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2(1-p-q)^{k-1}=\frac{2-p-q}{(p+q)^2}$  The variance is $\frac{1-p-q}{(p+q)^2}$

Comment: can you please explain a bit. otherwise, I can't even sure which one is correct as for someone completely newbie.

Comment: as for E[X] is  (p+q) sum $k(1-p-q)^k -1) $  and $E[X^2]$  is (p+q) sum  $k^2 (1-p-q) ^k-1)$.  why don't you square the k in (k-1) ?

Comment: @user95432 Which k should be squared?  For $E(X^2)$ it is squared.  Note for Latex, the exponent needs to be enclosed in {}.

Comment: E[x^2] = (p+q) sum k^2 (1-p-1)^{k-1}. (k-1) in this case, should we squared it ? any why? thank you again.

Comment: In general $E(X^n)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^nP_k$.